# Back calculating t-statistic in R

Tags: r, p-value, t-test

I have these information from an independent samples t-test.

```
p-value=0.989
```

```
sample size for group 1 (n1)= 17
```

```
sample size for group 2 (n2)= 18
```

```
mean difference= 0.30
```

I need the t-statistic for this test. I did trial and error with the code for p-value to get the t-statistic, that is 0.014
`2*pt(0.014, 33, lower.tail=F)`
#p=0.989

I need a the R code that gets the p-value and df as input, and provides 0.014 as the output.

Comment: You might have success looking at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ instead of stackoverflow, they specialize in these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need of `uniroot`. Use `qt`:

```
> qt(0.989/2, df = 33, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 0.01389174
```

Comment: Yes! I was looking for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Find the root of the indicated function assuming that it lies between 0 and 6:

giving:

```
uniroot(function(x, p) p - 2 * pt(x, 33, lower.tail = FALSE), c(0, 6), p = 0.989)
```

giving:

```
$root
[1] 0.01390167

$f.root
[1] 7.863003e-06

$iter
[1] 3

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

Here is another example:

```
2 * pt(1.901367, 19, lower.tail = FALSE)
## [1] 0.07252959

uniroot(function(x, p) p - 2 * pt(x, 19, lower.tail = FALSE), c(0, 6), p = 0.07252959)
```

giving:

$root
[1] 1.901365

$f.root
[1] -2.672236e-07

$iter
[1] 9

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05

Comment: I had changed that before your comment, not in response to it.